# Using memory mapping in C for reading binary

Tags: c, binaryfiles, mmap

I am trying to read data from a very large binary file and process it using memory mapping, so it can be read byte by byte. I am getting a few compiler errors while doing this, and I can't figure out what is causing them. I am doing this on a linux platform, for the record.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int fd;
char *data;

fd = open("data.bin", O_RDONLY);
pagesize = 4000;
data = mmap((caddr_t)0, pagesize, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, pagesize);
```

The errors I get are as follows:

> caddr not initialized
>
> R_RDONLY not initialized
>
> mmap has too few arguments.

I am using a Makefile to compile it, which looks like this:

```
all: order_book
CC = gcc 
CFLAGS = -std=c99

order_book: main.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o order_book main.c
clean: 
    rm -f order_book
```

What am I doing wrong, and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: It looks like you need to include another header file.  Perhaps `stdio.h` or `stdlib.h`?

Comment: I already had them. Forgot to mention them in the question

Comment: The code that fails is exactly the same as above. I use a makefile to compile my program. I have shown the contents in the above question box

Comment: do not use  `caddr_t` it is not POSIX just use NULL instead of `(caddr_t)(0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several errors, if this is indeed the *entire* piece of code that fails:

1. `O_RDONLY` requires `fcntl.h` to be included.
2. The code is defined outside of any function.
3. The first argument to `mmap` is a `void *`, so just use `NULL`.
4. `pagesize` is not declared.

The following compiles:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int fd;
char *data;

void main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  fd = open("data.bin", O_RDONLY);
  int pagesize = 4000;
  data = mmap(NULL, pagesize, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, pagesize);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for solving that problem! Now when I try to access data[0] it gives me a segfault. Do i need to do something else so that the file's data gets copied to the char pointer data ?

Comment: You need to check all of the return codes (from `open`, `mmap`, and any other function calls) to be sure they succeeded.  Check the man page for `mmap` at http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap for a complete example.